# Como llamar una función en Javascript desde otro archivo distinto con PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un formulario de ventas, intento imprimir un tikect de venta luego de validar que la venta sea a cargado correctamente en la bases de datos, este proceso de validacion lo hago con php en un archivo de llamado ventas.controlador.php, y para hacer que se imprima el tikect hice una funcion del lado del cliente con javascript en un archivo llamado Impresora.js en ese archivo tengo una función llamada impresoraepson(), esa funcion es la que hace que se imprima el ticket.

Intentos: el primer intento que hice fue que en el formulario en el boton de enviar el formulario coloque un Id para que mediante el evento del click dispara la función, eso funciono perfectamente... pero el problema esta en si la venta esta bien o no, igual se dispara la función.

Lo que quiero: es que después que todo el código PHP se ejecute dispare la función de impresoraepson()

Comment: Quizá no entendi tu pregunta, pero quiero aclarar algo: Si php se ejecuta en el servidor y js en el cliente como se supone que se comunican? Tienes algún cliente de js en el servidor?

Comment: `<script>document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', impresoraepson );</script>`

Comment: Bueno en realidad la función de javascrip se ejecuta por un boton en el formulario con un evento de click, pero la idea es que la función se ejecute luego de que en PHP valide ciertos datos y cargue las bases de datos de ser todo positivo es que se debe  imprimir un ticket, no intento enviar datos ni nada de eso, lo que quiero es que si todo en php se da bien luego se imprima el ticket

Comment: @InadesRD ¿Puedes reformular la pregunta añadiendo esto que comentas y añadiendo el código? Creo que nadie acabo de entender que es lo que pides, aun que sigo pensado lo mismo que dije antes

Comment: Es necesario que proveas un [mcve] a tu pregunta, puedes hacer clic en [edit] y añadir lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]  a tu pregunta le falta aclarar ciertos puntos podrías pasar por [ask]  para aprender a elaborar preguntas de calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta tiene una solución llamada `Ajax` necesitas `Jquery` para ello.

**Primero** importar lo necesario

```html
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

y no te olvides de llamar al archivo `Impresora.js` justo después de importar `Jquery`

**Segundo** en el `formulario_de_ventas.php`

html tendrias que tener algo asi

```html
<input type="submit" value="Yo imprimio la factura" id="btnimprimir" />
```

**Tercero** en el archivo `Impresora.js`

```html
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btnimprimir").click(function(){
       //hacemos una llamada ajax
        var url = "direccion_del_archivo/ventas.controlador.php";
        var factura = "000001";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:url,
            data:{
                 //aqui valores que quieras pasar como paremtro
                 factura:factura,
            },
            success:function(result){
                //aqui obtendriamos los valores que devolvemos
               console.log(result);
               //aqui la funcion que quieres que ese ejecute
               impresoraepson();
            }
        })
        
        //esto evita que la pagina se recargue
      return false
    })
});
```

**Cuarto** en `formulario_de_ventas.php`

En este documento los valores los obtendríamos con la variable `$_POST` en este ejemplo seria `$_POST['factura'];`

y para devolver un valor  lo hariamos con `echo`

Comment: segui tu recomendacion con algunos cambios , al darle click al boton #btnimprimir capture los valores que necesito, luego hice una consulta a la bases de datos con ajax, pero no logro que me arroje algun resulta esa consulta, esa funcion de ajax la tengo probada en otros modulos, con esto quiere decir que la funcion de ajax esta bien, lo que interpreto es que en el momento que hago la consulta aun no se ha cargado los datos en la bases de datos, la pregunta es sera que debo aplicar algun retardo antes de hacer la consulta a la bases de datos..

Answer (score -1):

En realidad en la vista que es llamada por ese controlador podes hacer tu invocación, por ejemplo si usas jQuery, podes hacer algo como;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 impresoraepson();
});
```

Con eso te aseguras que al cargar la página, se llame a esa función.